# C# Searching Through Different Groups of RichTextBoxes and Posting Them on CSV File

Tags: c#

Building on information I got last night, I have a 3 different groups of existing RichTextBoxes (meaning already painted on my form) called `CBox#, VBox# and TBox#` (the # indicates a numerical value ranging from 1 to n so `CBox1, CBox2, etc`). Now `CBox#` and `TBox#` only changes Changes Color from White to Red or Green while 'VBox#' contains some kind of string (like 5.0 V).

I set up some dummy data just to get some values and essentially, I am trying to scan through the current results and post them on a excel file (in this case, a csv file).

```
  using (var file = new StreamWriter("c:\\Test\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".csv"))
        {
            file.Write("Com Stat,");
            file.Write("Trip Stat,");
            file.WriteLine("Voltage");

            string ComRead = null;
            string TripRead = null;
            string VoltRead = null;

            CBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            CBox2.BackColor = Color.Green;
            CBox3.BackColor = Color.Red;
            CBox4.BackColor = Color.Green;
            CBox5.BackColor = Color.Green;
            CBox6.BackColor = Color.Green;
            CBox7.BackColor = Color.Green;
            CBox8.BackColor = Color.Red;
            CBox9.BackColor = Color.Green;
            CBox10.BackColor = Color.Green;

            TBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            TBox2.BackColor = Color.Green;
            TBox3.BackColor = Color.Green;
            TBox4.BackColor = Color.Green;
            TBox5.BackColor = Color.Green;
            TBox6.BackColor = Color.Green;
            TBox7.BackColor = Color.Green;
            TBox8.BackColor = Color.Green;
            TBox9.BackColor = Color.Red;
            TBox10.BackColor = Color.Green;

            VBox1.Text = "10.0 V";
            VBox2.Text = "5.0 V";
            VBox3.Text = "---";
            VBox4.Text = "5.0 V";
            VBox5.Text = "3.0 V";
            VBox6.Text = "5.0 V";
            VBox7.Text = "5.0 V";
            VBox8.Text = "---";
            VBox9.Text = "0.0 V";
            VBox10.Text = "5.0 V";


            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                foreach (var richBox in this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
                {
                    if ((richBox.Name.StartsWith("CBox" + i)) && (richBox.BackColor == Color.Green))
                    {
                        ComRead = "True";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ComRead = "False";
                    }

                    file.Write(ComRead + ",");

                    if ((richBox.Name.StartsWith("TBox" + i)) && (richBox.BackColor == Color.Green))
                    {
                        TripRead = "True";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TripRead = "False";
                    }

                    file.Write(TripRead + ",");

                    if (richBox.Name.StartsWith("VBox" + i))
                    {
                        VoltRead = richBox.Text;
                    }

                    file.WriteLine(VoltRead);
                }
        }

            file.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Demo Complete");
        }
```

Obviously, this doesn't work properly it will scan through each one individually and making something that should have been 11 lines on an excel file to 301 lines.

The obvious question is what did I do wrong? But I really want to know if there is a simpler way of doing that for loop I made at the end.

Comment: You're logic is flawed in the inner loop.  It will write multiple values for every rich text box on your form.

Comment: For example `if ((richBox.Name.StartsWith("CBox" + i)) && (richBox.BackColor == Color.Green))
                    {
                        ComRead = "True";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ComRead = "False";
                    }`  will write false every time it doesnt evaluate true.  Or in your case 12 times.  This logic issue is repeated each time and this is why you are seeing the issues.